# how to delete the keyboard shortcut key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to delete the keyboard shortcut key.

When I push the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and <kbd>click Left</kbd>-Click(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftClick</kbd>), I choose an active window.

I was trying to delete it on System Setting, but I couldn't find the Action for it.

Do you know how to delete <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftClick</kbd> shortcut that selects an active window?

Actually, this setting is for using CG software such as Blender, Unity3d, and so on.  In such softwares, the Alt key is used to manipulate the 3d view.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What are you trying to delete? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I fixed the description above. I'd like to delete the Alt+LeftClick shortcut that selects an active window.

Comment: Well, it's in CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) under General Options -> Key bindings -> Window menu (mouse icon), but Alt+Left click still does the same thing when I try changing it. I think you might need to log in and log out for it to take effect. BTW I'm using 14.04.

Comment: Oh wait it works if I use the buttons on my touchpad instead of the tap! I'll write you an answer.

Comment: I might have spoke too soon. I'm not sure what my computer is doing! Let me know if it works for you or if you need any directions.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I tried as you told me, but I can't make it... I'm trying dconf-tools as another person said, but I can't find the wm key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986831/how-to-delete-the-keyboard-shortcut-key-on-ubuntu/38986870?noredirect=1#comment65327688_38986870

Comment: I tried dconf-tools again and it works! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad you found a solution! The question you linked is gone. If you want, you can answer your question, and mark the answer as accepted, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks.  I posted the answer as you advised me.  It helped a lot.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, install dconf-tools.

To do that, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then to open it, type as follows on desktop

```
Alt+F2 → dconf-editor
```

Then the software starts and plaese scroll down to

```
org → gnome → desktop → wm → preferences → mouse-button-modifier
```

And you can set it to whichever key you like.

<<  [You can see the Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xta1.png)  >>

( Note: This post is written by d3r1ck. I repost this answer because the post was not appropriate for the StackOverflow and I deleted it. )